# Adding row to table

Tags: text-processing

I have several plain text tables (`table.txt`), with time series going from `2005` until `2099`. Unfortunately some of them are missing the last day of the time series `31.12.2099`, as follow:

```
YEAR MONTH DAY RES
2005 1     1   1000
2005 1     2   1001
[...]
2099 12    29  1002
2099 12    30  1003
```

How can I add the missing day of the time series (`31.12.2099`) by pasting the value (`RES`) of the previous day?
Considering the minimal example provided, the output should look like that:

```
YEAR MONTH DAY RES
2005 1     1   1000
2005 1     2   1001
[...]
2099 12    29  1002
2099 12    30  1003
2099 12    31  1003
```

Comment: This is a task with many sub-tasks. Which of these sub-tasks is causing you problems?

Comment: Are you permitted to use `awk` or `perl`?

Comment: @StigHemmer - The first problematic task is to find which table missed the 31.12.2099. Afterward I think I am able to paste the value of the previous day.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - Definitely permitted to use them!

Comment: How are the columns delimited? A single tab? Multiple spaces?

Comment: @steve, when you say "using the shell" we understand that you are limited to builtin commands like `while` and `read` and cannot non-shell tools like `awk` or `sed` or `cut` etc. Just an FYI to explain why Mark asked about `awk` and `perl`. The phrasing of your question seemed to exclude those.

Comment: Also, is it only 31/12/2099 that is missing or can there also be a missing 31/12/2015 or something? Does your question boil down to simply adding a single line at the end of each of those text files?

Comment: @terdon - Thank you very much for all those information! In fact you´re right my question could be sums up by simply adding a line at the end of each files missing the 31.12.2099.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{a=$0}1; END{$0=a; if($1==2099&&$2==12&&$3==30){$3=31;print}}' file | column -t
```

- `r=$0` set the `a` variable to the whole line.
- `1` a true condition that all line are printed
- `END{...}` that block is executed when all lines are processed

  - `$1==2099&&$2==12&&$3==30` if the last line was december 30th, 2099 (the 13th is missing)
  - `$3=31` set the day to `31`
  - `print` and print that additional line.
- `column -t` is to columnate the list.

---

The result with your input file:

```
YEAR  MONTH  DAY  RES
2005  1      1    1000
2005  1      2    1001
...
2099  12     29   1002
2099  12     30   1003
2099  12     31   1003
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file names all start with `table` (if they don't, just change the glob pattern to something that matches all of them), you can do:

```
for file in table*; do
    awk -vi="2099 12    31" '1;END{if($0!=i){print i,$NF}}' "$file" > "$file".new
done
```

The `awk` command defines the variable `i` to be the missing line. The `1;` just prints every line and the `END{}` block is executed once the entire file has been read. When inside the `END{}` block, `$0` will be the last line read, the last line of the file. If that is not equal to the value of `i`, print `i` and the last field `(NF)` of the last line of the file.

Comment: @Costas d'oh! Of course, very good point. Thanks and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The script adds to all `table` files which have `30` in the last line followed by 2 space and 4 symbols `RES` the new line with `2099 12    31  RES(from line before)`:

```
sed -i '$ s/30\(  ....\)$/&\n2099 12    31\1/' table*
```